# Eu realmente preciso partir de uma main para rodar um schedule no java?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, thread, scheduler

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, e agora cheguei em um ponto em que terei um processo rodando em paralelo em minha aplicação(em background) todo dia em um horário x. Para testar o processo, eu fiz uma classe dentro do projeto com uma main, e rodei ela separadamente, legal tudo funcionou como eu esperava.

Porém quando fui tentar deixar o código funcionando normalmente, deletando a main e deixando apenas uma classe, eu tive o seguinte erro **"Syntax Error, ConstructorHeaderName Expected instead."**

**Schedula o processo.**

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class ScheduleBases {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 24);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


          // creating timer task, timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        tarefaDiaria td = new tarefaDiaria();

          // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(td,today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));      
       }
}
```

**Ação que irá rodar no horário especificado**

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.util.TimerTask;

public class tarefaDiaria extends TimerTask  {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("OPA FUNCINOU!");

    }

}
```

Moral da história, eu preciso que ao "ligar" meu servidor e rodar minha aplicação web, esse processo esteja ativado, e rode no horário que eu especifiquei... Eu tentei rodar deixando a main, mas ele não roda no horário, e ao tirar a main tenho o erro.

[image: Problema compilação]

---

**(Edit: Estou rodando em um Tomcat comum)**

Comment: Sim, você precisa de um `main` para rodar algo a partir da linha de comando. Ele é o ponto de entrada. Você também precisa de um método (seja ele `main` ou qualquer outro) para o seu código, como você percebeu pelos erros de compilação não é possível rodar `statements` como `today.set...` diretamente no corpo da classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheguei a solução usando um webListener:

```
@WebListener
public class ScheduleBases implements ServletContextListener {


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("entrei no schedule valendo!");
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 31);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        // creating timer task, timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        tarefaDiaria td = new tarefaDiaria();

        // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(td,today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }



    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {




    }        

}
```

minha thread começou as 14:31 exatamente.

Comment: Por curiosidade, ao invés do `WebListener` porque não uma aplicação *stand-alone* e uma entrada no `cron` (*nix) ou `control schedtasks` (Windows)? Eu entendo as vantagens de centralizar todo o código em um único projeto, mas do ponto de vista de modularidade, robustez e utilização de recursos vale a pena separar as coisas.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Oi, eu inicialmente tinha pensado em fazer um app stand-alone para essa tarefa, mas acontece que trabalho em uma empresa que adora por barreiras sempre que você quer adotar qualquer tecnologia "nova" ou comunicação entre diversos apps. Como tenho uma deadline surrealista a cumprir, fui no mais fácil, que é integrar tudo. Tendo dito isso, futuramente quando for necessário maior performance, creio que terei de usar um app stand alone, de fato!

Comment: Olá @user94991. Entendo a situação. Fique a vontade para aceitar sua própria resposta. Esse é um bom indicativo para usuários que chegarem ao site com um problema semelhante.

Comment: pode deixar @AnthonyAccioly , porém o site só me permite fazer isso amanhã, amanhã marco a resposta como correta, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais padrão para isso é usar [timers do JavaEE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

No seu exemplo, você poderia fazer assim:

```
@Singleton
public class ScheduleBases {

@Schedule(hour="02/24", minute="30")
public void scheduledTask() {

    System.out.println("OPA FUNCINOU!");
}
```

Assim o método "scheduledTask" iria executar às 02:30 da madrugada, e após isso, a cada 24 horas novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela Resposta, infelizmente estou em fim de expediente e só poderei testar amanhã pela manhã.

Comment: só gostaria de salientar que estou usando tomcat comum, não é tomcateEE, nem glassfish, não sei se tenho suporte a esse tipo de schedule, mas vou testar

Comment: realmente, por usar o Tomcat mais comum eu não tenho acesso à essas ferramentas, vou ver se consigo uma outra maneira... Obrigado!